pandas convert continuous duration column to start and end colum
I would like to convert duration column to start and end column. I try below code, it works as expected but it not a perfect way.
import pandas as pd

def main():
    data = [
        ['A',7],
        ['B',5],
        ['C',5],
        ['D',15],
        ['E',5]
        ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','duration'])
    data = []
    for idx,row in df.iterrows():
        name = row['name']
        dur = row['duration']
        if idx == 0:
            start = 0
            end = start + dur
        else:
            start = end
            end = start + dur
        data.append([name,start,dur,end])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','start','duration','end'])
    print(df)

main()    

Excepted results:
   name  start  duration  end
 0    A      0         7    7
 1    B      7         5   12
 2    C     12         5   17
 3    D     17        15   32
 4    E     32         5   37


Just use cumsum to get the running total and subtract from duration to get the start . df['end'] = df['duration'].cumsum()    df['start'] = df['end'] - df['duration']

Just use cumsum to get the running total and subtract from duration to get the start .
df['end'] = df['duration'].cumsum() 
df['start'] = df['end'] - df['duration']


A possible solution, which uses cumsum to calculate column end, and hence calculates column start as the difference between column end and duration:
cols = ['name', 'start', 'duration', 'end']
d = df.assign(end = df['duration'].cumsum())
d.assign(start = d['end'] - d['duration'])[cols]

Output:
  name  start  duration  end
0    A      0         7    7
1    B      7         5   12
2    C     12         5   17
3    D     17        15   32
4    E     32         5   37

